# Using NSTimer to calculate the time difference between two float numbers

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, nstimer

I have a float number that is changing according to the microphone input.

I want to make a decision if the float value goes over 0.2 and it stays for 0.3 sec or less over it.

So how to use NSTimer or any other way to get it ?

this is my code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"dev/null"];
NSDictionary *settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0],             AVSampleRateKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleLossless],  AVFormatIDKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt:1],                     AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityMax],AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                          nil];
NSError *error;
recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:settings error:&error];
if (recorder) {
    [recorder prepareToRecord];
    recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
    [recorder record];
    levelTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(levelTimerCallBack:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
else {
    NSLog(@"fail");
}
}


 - (void)levelTimerCallBack:(NSTimer *)timer {
[recorder updateMeters];

const double ALPHA = 0.05;
double peakPowerForChannel = pow(10, (0.05 * [recorder peakPowerForChannel:0]));
lowPassResults = ALPHA * peakPowerForChannel + (1.0 - ALPHA) * lowPassResults;
if (lowPassResults > 0.2 && lowPassResults < 0.5) {
           // here to get the length of time that lowPassResults stays between 0.2 and 0.5
}
}

@end
```

Comment: I have no idea about using the microphone, but it seems like it ought to have some continuous monitoring functionality to feed you the values rather than you having to constantly poll for the values. Check its API to see if you can register for a continuous stream of values in real time. If so then what you want to do will be easy

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't very clear. All a timer is going to do for you is trigger your code to do something on a regular interval.

You could use a timer to trigger sampling the audio level at a regular interval.

This sentence is confusing though:

> I want to make a decision if the float value goes over 0.2 and it
>   stays for 0.3 sec or less over it.

Do you mean that you want to know if the level goes over .2 and stays at > .2 for .3 seconds or more?

A timer will not be a good way to monitor the volume level continuously. You'll only see the level at your sample interval.

To do that I think you may need to use lower level audio processing like AVRecorder or audio units, where you get callbacks on very short intervals.

Comment: Yes, as you mentioned in the 6th line. Also when testing the app, the action which executes when lowPassResults > 0.2 && lowPassResults < 0.5 doesn't execute only one time, it may run for more than 100 times! , So how to make it run just one time when the if condition is true? @Duncan

Comment: By adding logic that changes a boolean instance variable when it first detects the state you are looking for.